# pdf generation in iphone with date and time stamped

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pdf-generation

I am generating PDF report in my application,i want the report to be date and time stamped can any body explain how to do that actually,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just draw a UILabel into your pdf context that is creating this report? Should be relatively easy. You can also create a new pdf context, draw the pdf in it, and add the label, then save it as a new document.